# how can I properly call an API that depends on the response of another API Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

i have an API "breedImageByID(referenceImageId: String)" that depends on "getBreeds()" Api's  to get the referenceImageId. after getting the data   i need to populate each item in a list  with getBreeds data and breedImageByID() data. but after doing this it behaves weirdly, the breedImageByID() image  does not properly align with getBreed() data to populate each item in the list. how do I resolve this.

BreedScreen:

```
@Composable
fun BreedListItem(
    breed: BreedItem,
    catImage: CatImage,
    viewModel: BreedSharedViewModel,
    navController: NavController
) {

    val breedImageURL = remember {
        breed.reference_image_id.let { imageId ->
            viewModel.breedImageByID.value.data?.url ?: ""
        }
    }

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(6.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(18.dp))
            .background(Color.Gray)
            .clickable {
                viewModel.addBreedItem(breed)
                navController.navigate(DetailsNavScreen.BreedsDetail.route)
            },
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(120.dp)
                .height(80.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
        ) {
            SubcomposeAsyncImage(
                model = breedImageURL,
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
            )
        }

        Text(
            text = breed.name,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 15.dp),
            fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
            fontSize = 17.sp
        )
    }
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
}
```

BreedSharedViewModel:

```
val breeds: MutableState<NetworkResult<GetBreeds>> =
    mutableStateOf(NetworkResult.Loading())

val breedImageByID: MutableState<NetworkResult<CatImage>> =
    mutableStateOf(NetworkResult.Loading())


private fun getBreeds() = viewModelScope.launch {

    repository.getBreeds().collect { values ->
        breeds.value = values

        values.data?.forEach {
            it.reference_image_id?.let { imageId ->
                breedImageByID(imageId)
                breedImageByID.value.data?.let {
                    it1 ->
                    Log.i("catImageID", it1.url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun breedImageByID(referenceImageId: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.getCatImageByID(referenceImageId).collect { values ->
        breedImageByID.value = values
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`launch`, `async` are coroutine builders available in kotlin. `launch` function follows `fire and forget` method, which essentially means it will launch a coroutine and forget about its result. Whereas `aync` returns an instance of `Deferred` which has function called `await` that can be used to wait for the result. Inside a coroutine builder, you can create multiple coroutines that are not synchronous necessarily. What you are trying to doing here is also the same. You launch a different coroutine, when you call `breedImageByID` that won't wait for its result. To make it synchronous, try `await` as below

```
suspend fun breedImageByID(referenceImageId: String) = viewModelScope.async {
    repository.getCatImageByID(referenceImageId)
}.await()
```

Note that I have added `suspend` keyword before the function definition. The above code makes network call to breed for every cat image id.

To make it more clean, we can make `getCatImageByID` as suspend function by adding `suspend` keyword and directly call the `breedImageByID` as below

```
//declaration
suspend fun breedImageByID(referenceImageId: String) = repository.getCatImageByID(referenceImageId)

//function calling
values.data?.forEach {
    it.reference_image_id?.let { imageId ->
        val breed = breedImageByID(imageId)
        Log.i("catImageID", breed.url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,  yes that works when when i log the ViewModel result, but  the breedImageByID is still misaligned  with each  getBreeds() item.. i think the issue is coming from the  UI layer.how do I ensure that the breed images  fetched are associated with their corresponding breed items properly..I'm not still sure how to resolve it

Comment: Did you try making `getCatImageByID` as suspend?

Comment: yes I did make getCatImageByID suspend

Comment: Can you please post your latest code here? Or as a github gist?

Comment: Hi, thanks alot.. I was finally able to find a workaround  to it.. so basically what I did was i combined the catImage 
and breed in a  BreedDetails() data class  and appended it to a list, to be observed by the ui.   https://gist.github.com/erinfolami/520d3e3924151fe0ce645cc35347779c